# Some results for system of differential equations (random walk/road in \Z^n)

Tags: analysis, entropy, differential

I need a proof for three results about the following system of differential equations. We can consider any regularity for the functions. The system is given by:

$u_i'=-\lambda (u_i-u_{i-1}) - \lambda (u_i - u_{i+1})$

The results that I need are:

1. For a solution $u_1$, ... , $u_N$, proof that

$\frac{d}{dt}\sum_{i=1}^{N}u_i^2 \leq 0$

2. For a solution $u_1$, ... , $u_N$, with $u_i(t) > 0 \quad \forall t \geq 0, \quad i=1,..., N$ proof that

$\frac{d}{dt}\sum_{i=1}^{N}u_i log \, u_i \leq 0$

This last sum represent the negavity of the entropy in the physic system.

3. Proof that the last expression is also true for a solution $u_1$, ... , $u_N$ of the system given by $u_i' = -\lambda u_i + \lambda u_{i-1}$, with $u_i(t) > 0 \quad \forall t \geq 0, \quad i=1,..., N$